# How to check if facebook fan page exists with javascript?

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk

In my app, I have a facebook field that can refer to a facebook user or to a facebook user fanpage.

I want to render the facebook fan page like box only if the fanpage exists in Facebook. Is there a way to do this with the Javascript SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use the [Facebook JS SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) you can do this after initializing the FB object

```
    FB.api('/the_fanpage_path', function(response) {
      if(response.is_published) {
        // it is a Fan Page!
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use jQuery and can figure out the pattern for the URL of those pages, you can use jQuery.get to check whether they exist or not.  If you don't use jQuery, you can do the same thing with raw XmlHttpRequests.

For example, if the URL is "www.facebook.com/fanpage/{{username}}", you can do:

```
function startCheckForFanPage(username) {
    $.get("www.facebook.com/fanpage/" + username, function(response) {
        // if response.showsThere'sAPageThere, do X
        // otherwise, do Y
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I get a "same origin policy" error with this solution.

Comment: There are ways to handle that; this link should be helpful http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/archive/11-10-03/using_cors_with_all_modern_browsers.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to load the FB SDK, you can do an AJAX get request to eg. http://graph.facebook.com/facebook. This works with the cross origin policy because graph.facebook.com allows different domains.

The response is in JSON so something like this would work:

```
function startCheckForFanPage(username) {
    $.get("graph.facebook.com/" + username, function(response) {
        if (response)
        // otherwise, do Y
    }, function() {
        // Handle 404 or other failures here
    })
}
```

EDIT: This no longer works